# Beginning android game programming

Tags: android

Okay, so I want to get into programming games for android. (I am not an absolute beginner, as I already have an app on the amazon app store) I have searched the Internet and found nothing of particular use.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

By the way this is my first question on stack exchange, so if I'm going about this wrong, please help me.

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: What I mean when I say 'the right direction' is a resource of sorts to get me started with sprites and canvases and the like.

ANOTHER EDIT: I have decided that I will use unity for my game, which will be 2D. A tutorial for that would be helpful. :)

Comment: The right direction? http://upload.storiesspace.com/497996374-1367850293137-bugs_bunny_he_went_that_a_way_gif.gif

Comment: Thanks for  the laugh, but I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: `on the amazon app store` why would you ever do that?

Comment: @Raid no problem, I think you need to clarify what you mean by the right direction before anyone can help you. Make an edit to your question to say what you are looking for specifically. Good luck.

Comment: I don't have the money to register on Google play right now. It is on my to do list though.

Comment: There. I edited the question.

Comment: This isn't really the right form of question for Stackoverflow, this board is for specific problems that need to be solved rather than the provision of general advice.

That said, if you're interested in game development, look into the Unity game engine, it can be used to create Android games and is good for beginners.

Comment: @Glen Pierce could you point me towards a tutorial for Unity? The game I want to code is 2D, if that helps you.

Comment: No jokes now. You should really learn [how to use the site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid trolling your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way for a beginner to get into game development is start using some framework/engine (Unity3d,libGdx,etc) . You will understand that making game is pretty hard even on high-level tools (and drawing on canvas even simple frame-by-frame animation with correct memory management is not simple task).

If this is exactly what you need try some Java game tutorial (like this one http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/) and backport it as android version. The methods looks very similar.

Comment: Can you point me towards a unity tutorial? My game will be 2D, if that helps.

Comment: Official documentation is pretty nice. https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation

Comment: Thank you! This should be exactly what I need. You're awesome! :)